# Incorrect Holm-adjusted p-values in psych::corr.test()?

Tags: r

In preparing teaching materials on Holm-adjusted *p*-values, I set out to make the adjustments both by hand and via *R*'s psych::corr.test().  All 26 by-hand and by-*R* adjusted *p*-values are in accord except except two.  I assume this is user error, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

The code below will:

1. Reproduce the p-values in question (psych package).
2. Rank unadjusted p-values (lowest=1).
3. Compute Holm p-values as p(unadj.) * rank.
4. Compare adjusted p-values.

```r
library(psych)  
dat = state.x77  
R.out = corr.test(dat)  
R.out$p  
unadj.p = ifelse(lower.tri(R.out$p) == F, NA, R.out$p)  
p.ranks = 29 - rank(unadj.p, na.last = T)  
p.ranks = matrix(ifelse(p.ranks < 1, NA, p.ranks), 8, 8)  
myHolm = unadj.p * p.ranks  
myHolm = ifelse(myHolm > 1, 1, myHolm)  
myHolm = t(myHolm)  
round(myHolm, 4)  
round(R.out$p, 4)  
myHolm == R.out$p
```

Results of analyses are shown below.  Adjusted p-values in the first table (mine) match those in the second table--from corr.test()--except the two in row 1 columns 7:8.

This is my first post here--sorry for any deviations from posting norms.

```
>   round(myHolm,4)  
     [,1] [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]  
[1,]   NA    1 1.0000 1.0000 0.2328 1.0000 0.2398 0.8765  
[2,]   NA   NA 0.0286 0.2343 1.0000 0.0000 1.0000 0.1616  
[3,]   NA   NA     NA 0.0002 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000  
[4,]   NA   NA     NA     NA 0.0000 0.0002 0.7918 1.0000  
[5,]   NA   NA     NA     NA     NA 0.0065 0.0011 1.0000  
[6,]   NA   NA     NA     NA     NA     NA 0.1583 0.2510  
[7,]   NA   NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA 1.0000  
[8,]   NA   NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA  
>   round(R.out$p,4)  
           Population Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad  Frost   Area  
Population     0.0000 1.0000     1.0000   1.0000 0.2328  1.0000 0.2510 1.0000  
Income         0.1467 0.0000     0.0286   0.2343 1.0000  0.0000 1.0000 0.1616  
Illiteracy     0.4569 0.0015     0.0000   0.0002 0.0000  0.0000 0.0000 1.0000  
Life Exp       0.6387 0.0156     0.0000   0.0000 0.0000  0.0002 0.7918 1.0000  
Murder         0.0146 0.1080     0.0000   0.0000 0.0000  0.0065 0.0011 1.0000  
HS Grad        0.4962 0.0000     0.0000   0.0000 0.0003  0.0000 0.1583 0.2510  
Frost          0.0184 0.1141     0.0000   0.0660 0.0001  0.0088 0.0000 1.0000  
Area           0.8765 0.0095     0.5938   0.4581 0.1106  0.0179 0.6828 0.0000  
>   myHolm == R.out$p  
           Population Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad Frost  Area  
Population         NA   TRUE       TRUE     TRUE   TRUE    TRUE FALSE FALSE  
Income             NA     NA       TRUE     TRUE   TRUE    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  
Illiteracy         NA     NA         NA     TRUE   TRUE    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  
Life Exp           NA     NA         NA       NA   TRUE    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  
Murder             NA     NA         NA       NA     NA    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  
HS Grad            NA     NA         NA       NA     NA      NA  TRUE  TRUE  
Frost              NA     NA         NA       NA     NA      NA    NA  TRUE  
Area               NA     NA         NA       NA     NA      NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO, your first post looks great so no problems there.

In terms of your calculation you have run into a problem because when multiplying `unadj.p * p.ranks` the order of your ranks is not preserved. For example, if you inspect the row 1 column 7 value, or `[1,7]`, (0.2398 in yours) it is lower than the row 7 column 8 value, or `[7,8]` (0.2510). This should not be the case since your `p.ranks` matrix shows that they should be rank 13 and 14 respectively (with the `[1,7]` being the higher of the two).

Instead of simply multiplying `unadj.p * p.ranks`, we should first order them, and then take the cumulative maximum of the resulting multiplication.

```r
    library(psych)  
    dat = state.x77  
    R.out = corr.test(dat)  
    R.out$p  
    unadj.p = ifelse(lower.tri(R.out$p)==F,NA,R.out$p)  

    # convert into vector for ease of calculation
    p <- as.numeric(unadj.p)
    # remove missing values
    p <- p[!is.na(p)]

    # find the ranks of p
    pr <- rank(p)

    # put p in order
    po <- p[order(p)]

    # put ranks in order (1 is smallest)
    pro <- pr[order(pr, decreasing = T)]

    # now they are in order we can take the CUMULATIVE MAX to preserve order
    pcum <- cummax(po * pro)

    # now put back in our order and stick in our matrix
    myHolm <-unadj.p
    myHolm[!is.na(myHolm)] <- pcum[pr]


    myHolm = ifelse(myHolm>1,1,myHolm)  
    myHolm = t(myHolm)  

    myHolm == R.out$p
```

```
#            Population Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad Frost Area
# Population         NA   TRUE       TRUE     TRUE   TRUE    TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# Income             NA     NA       TRUE     TRUE   TRUE    TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# Illiteracy         NA     NA         NA     TRUE   TRUE    TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# Life Exp           NA     NA         NA       NA   TRUE    TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# Murder             NA     NA         NA       NA     NA    TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# HS Grad            NA     NA         NA       NA     NA      NA  TRUE TRUE
# Frost              NA     NA         NA       NA     NA      NA    NA TRUE
# Area               NA     NA         NA       NA     NA      NA    NA   NA
```

Comment: @davefest what I mean is that multiplying the p-value by the rank shouldn't affect the ordering. A simple example: 1.5 is greater than 1.4 but 13*1.5 < 14*1.4. Hence, after the adjustment the order of our p-values has changed which shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @Chris.  Note that when describing my ranks 13 and 14, I think you were associating the *adjusted* p values with the ranks from the *raw* p values.  R.out$p[7,1]=.0184 ranks 13 and R.out$p[8,6]=.0179 ranks 14, so I think my ranks were working without sorting.  Many thanks for the info re. cummax().  I don't remember that from Holm (1979), but it does prevent significance after the first non-siginificant result and fully explains the discrepancy between my calculations and the corr.test() results.  I will definitely revisit the paper.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, ok, got it.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @davefest yes your ranks were working as you intended but I was just trying to explain why the cummax was necessary. I think you understand that now anyway. If you're satisfied with this solution, please hit the green tick to accept it as the answer and feel free to upvote too :)